# Tables permission_block and permission_variable not created after SUPEE-6788

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, magento-community, patches, supee-6788

After applying the Magento patch SUPEE-6788, I find that the tables `permission_block` and `permission_variable` are not created in the database. How should I start investigate this problem? (The Magento version is 1.9.0.1)

Comment: Did the patch apply correctly? Have you tried clearing your cache and refreshing the page?

Comment: The patch claimed to be applied correctly. Cache clearing was done, but I would think that this is not a matter of cache, since the problem lies in the MySQL database, not on the web pages.

Comment: When you clear the cache and go to the frontend it runs all the update scripts for magento which is what the patch does. If you have the n98 tool installed you can run the following `sys:setup:run `

Comment: You are right. After applying the patch, I did a 'clear cache' followed by a reload of the front-end home page, the tables correctly appeared in the database.

Comment: Awesome. Just added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answered in comments.

You will need to clear the cache a reload the homepage in order for magento's update scripts to be called. Alternatively you can download [N98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) and run the `sys:setup:run` command to run the updates.

Comment: If this answer does not help you then you should also check out [this answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/88068/6243)