# Tables permission_block and permission_variable did not get created after SUPEE-6788

Tags: patches, upgrade-script, supee-6788, directive-whitelist

I installed the patch SUPEE-6788 on my local website and everything went fine. I uploaded all modified files to our production website but tables `permission_block` and `permission_variable` did not get created.

I have done the same steps on other 2 websites before this one and everything went fine (one has the same version).

What can I do?

I have already cleared the cache and visited the home page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tables should be created as part of the upgrade of `Mage_Admin` from version 1.6.1.1 to 1.6.1.2.  You can verify that the setup/upgrade scripts succeeded by checking the `version` and `data_version` fields in the `core_resource` table:

```
select * from core_resource where code = 'admin_setup';
```

Both values should show version 1.6.1.2, if either of them do not have this value then it's likely that the upgrade failed.

Comment: Both on my local machine and production server values are:
version: 1.6.1.2 - data_version 1.6.1.2

Comment: Tables permission_block and permission_variable are both missing from the production database

Comment: it's hard to say for certain what the current state of things in your system is.  You could update the `core_resource` record to say that `admin_setup` is version 1.6.1.1, clear the cache, and reload the homepage again.  The upgrade script appears to only impact those tables so this *should* be safe.  Alternatively you could use `mysqldump` to copy the tables from one of your other installations to production.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick! I updated the core_resource record to say that admin_setup is version 1.6.1.1, cleared the cache, visited the home page and after that tables appeared!