# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in Permissions/BlockController.php on line 113 - After Applying SUPEE-6788

Tags: magento-1.8, supee-6788

PHP Fatal error After Applying SUPEE-6788:

> Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
>   on line 113

First I am not able to apply the patch `SUPEE-6788`. It said

> -e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully

Followed the Steps provided in link "[Why does PATCH_SUPEE-6788 appear to have no effect on a 1.7.0.2 installation?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/why-does-patch-supee-6788-appear-to-have-no-effect-on-a-1-7-0-2-installation/87903#87903)" and then i was able to apply the patch.

But some Magento blocks are missing at the Home page. After a long search in Google I found that we have to create blocks under `System > Permissions > Blocks`

But I am not able to access it, because some tables not getting created `( permission_block and permission_variable )`

This problem was solved by following procedure ( [Tables permission_block and permission_variable did not get created after SUPEE-6788](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/tables-permission-block-and-permission-variable-did-not-get-created-after-supee) )

But now I am not Able to edit or create block under permissions, Only List view visible. Getting the above mentioned error

Comment: did you solve this ?? I am having the same issue

Comment: No not yet. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 7):

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml

This error is generated when layout cache hasn't been updated or admin.xml is missing the following code.

```
<!-- admin permissions block edit page -->
<adminhtml_permissions_block_edit>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/permissions_block_edit" name="adminhtml.permissions.block.edit"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_permissions_block_edit>
<!-- admin permissions variable edit page -->
```

Comment: Also check using adminhtml_permissions_role_editrole in nay other xml file.If it is present there then need to be updated also.

Answer (score 1):

One can manually add/edit/remove the entries in the database. The table `permission_block` contains the columns `block_id, block_name, is_allowed` where one can simply add a block to the whitelist by entering the name and setting `is_allowed` to `1`.

Not exactly an answer/solution, rather a workaround....

Answer (score 1):

Below solution worked for me:
Replcae below code:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('adminhtml.permissions.block.edit')
            ->setData('action', $this->getUrl('*/permissions_block/save'));
```

with

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/permissions_block_edit')
            ->setData('action', $this->getUrl('*/permissions_block/save'));
```

Do similar for `VariableController.php` same **line 113**.